# Extend Nautilus close button all the way in the corner

Tags: 18.04, nautilus

In Ubuntu 18.04, I have moved the top bar to the bottom of the screen. This way when I want to click the top-right closing button, it is far easier since I can just yank the cursor into the top-right corner and click. This is true for all programs except Nautilus, for which I need to move the cursor very precisely to the cross, and then click to close it.

It this configurable such that the closing button on Nautilus works like all other programs?

Comment: Nautilus and some gnome programs like gnome-terminal uses [Client-side decoration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-Side_Decoration) which means those buttons are drawn by the application not the the window manager. So I don't think it's easily customizable. But still changing the global Gtk theme (or the nautilus theme , if it's possible) might help you.